# Is it possible for a single Teams bot to have more than 1 simultaneous chat conversation with the same user?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

For a remote advisor solution, we would like a Teams bot to be able to carry on multiple 1:1 chat conversations with the same user (advisor) in independent chat windows.

Currently of course you can only have one chat widow between 2 participants and it appears only 1 conversation ID. (Using threaded conversations  has cognitive overload on the adviser to keep track of multiple threads, so independent chat windows is preferred)

What are some techniques to make this possible, other than to use multiple cooperating bots?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, because when you create a conversation with a user you use tenantId + userId, which results in a conversation. There is no way to have multiple ones.. it is like 1-on-1 chat with a person, you cannot have many of them.

As an alternative, you can create public or private group chat and invite there a person and the bot. You can many of them.

Comment: Hi Leo.  Group chat is what we do in SfB today using UCMA for this case, but in Teams it is not possible for the bot in group chat to get a copy of the messages of the group chat in real-time (either the bot has to be @mentioned every time or the Graph has to be used to poll for the messages in the group chat which increases the complexity and slows down the processing of messages by the bot)

Comment: when you tell "create public or private group chat and invite there a person" by person you mean support operator or customer? I don't think we can invite generic user from other sources to teams and i don't think we can create multiple group chats where we have operatorA+botA in it, or am i missing smth?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have multiple 1:1 chats with the same Bot. Each user will only have a single chat window with one Bot. If you want this bot to be able to interact with many people at once you can add it to teams scope.

Comment: Thanks. The use case for the bot is to mediate communication between 2 users (u1, a1)  in a back to back situation.  The 2nd user is a remote adviser and needs to participate in multiple mediated sessions with different users at the same time.  (u1->bot->a1, u2>bot->a1, u3->bot->a1 etc).  Bot needs to inspect all messages

Comment: Multiple Group chat would have been an option but the restrictions placed on the bot framework by MS where a bot can not get a stream of all messages in real-time even in the group chat in which it is participating means that approach is also not suitable.  Not every message can be @mentioned and polling via the graph is slow, and also likely to run into other throttling limits in the scaleout)

Comment: Bot only receives messages where it is @mentioned. That is the current behaviour of the apps.

Comment: Yes, and that is a show stopper for many apps of this nature in the customer support environment.  For years we had a great experience with SfB/UCMA, and since migration to Teams many of the existing apps are severely hobbled.

Comment: Bots can only listen to the messages when they are @mentioned. That is the default behaviour today.